# (Linguagem C) Não estou conseguindo efetivamente fazer a comparação de if entre duas chars

Tags: c, if, comparação

Este é o código inicial de menu do programa:

```
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<conio.c>
    #include<time.h>
    #include<locale.h>

    void inicio();
    void logar();
    void cadastrar();
    void sobre();
    void sair();
    void cadastroAdministrativo();
    
    int opcao;               
    char valor[];
    char token[] = "a";

    int main()  
    {
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"");      
    inicio();
    }       
       
    void inicio(){
    system("cls");
    printf("Bem vindo a central da coleta de dados da Secretaria Municipal de Gestão!\n");
    printf("1-Logar\n");
    printf("2-Cadastrar\n");
    printf("3-Sobre\n");
    printf("4-Sair\n");
    printf("Opção: ");
    scanf("%i",&opcao);
    switch (opcao){
          case 1:logar(); break;
          case 2:cadastroAdministrativo(); break;
          case 3:sobre(); break;
          case 4:sair(); break;
          }
    }
```

e esta é a parte que esta dando problema:

```
void cadastroAdministrativo(){
opcao = 1;     
do {
fflush(stdin);    
system("cls");        
printf("Por favor digite o token de administração:\n");
scanf("%c",&valor);

if (valor == token){
printf("Placeholder\n");
scanf("%i",&valor);               
} else {
system("cls");
printf("Você errou! deseja:\n");
printf("1-Tentar novamente\n");
printf("2-Voltar\n");
printf("Opção: ");
fflush(stdin);
scanf("%i",&opcao);
} } while(opcao == 1); 
inicio();
}
```

como vocês podem ver essa função cadastroAdministrativo(); é chamada se eu escolher a opção 2 no menu inicial na variavel opcao, e quando essa função é chamada, eu devo digitar o token de administração (que serviria pro programa saber se eu sou um administrador ou não) e então ele autenticaria e me deixaria continuar, o problema, é q quando eu faço essa comparação

```
if (valor == token){
printf("Placeholder\n");
scanf("%i",&valor);               
}
```

independente do que eu digite, a comparação retorna um resultado de falso, como podem ver o token na declaração de variaveís é "a" então eu teria que digitar "a" para funcionar, so que mesmo eu digitando a ele não valida, independente do que eu digite ele sempre retorna falso logo o programa não funciona como deveria, é isso.

Answer (score -1):

Para comparar array de char, use a *function* `strcmp`, disponível no `string.h`.

Inclusive pode fazer um token mais "seguro" usando uma pequena palavra por exemplo:

```
char token[] = "senha";
char valor[10];
....
scanf("%s",valor);

if (strcmp(token,valor == 0){
   printf("Placeholder\n");
   scanf("%i",&valor);               
} else {
  ....
}
```

Como pode ver, `strcmp` retorna 0 (zero) quando as strings são iguais: https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/

Pode ver funcionando aqui: [inserir a descrição do link aqui](https://ideone.com/Le9OGr)
(se quiser fazer testes, click em "fork" e mude o valor a ser digitado em "stdin")